# Iterate through subdirectories and execute an awk script against certain files

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have a directory named ../words that contains a number of subdirectories(words/blabla,words/blabla), in turn each subdirectory contains two types of files (.*1.txt) and (.*2.txt) .
What I need, it is to run an AWK script against each one of these files.

Could it be something like?

```
for d in words/*
do
    for f in .*[0-9].txt
    do
    awk -f script.awk ${f}
done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a modern shell like `bash` or `zsh`, you can use something like:

```
for i in words/*/*{1,2}.txt; do awk -f script.awk "$i"; done
```

If, for whatever reason, you need compatibility with `/bin/sh`, you can use this slightly more verbose and less readable solution

```
for i in words/*/*1.txt words/*/*2.txt; do awk -f script.awk "$i"; done
```

Comment: It works perfectly!! as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for f in words/*/.*[12].txt
do
    awk -f script.awk "$f"
done
```

Comment: I get this error, probably because the version of bash on cygwin `awk: iterate.awk: 2: fatal: can not open the file /*/.* words [12] .txt 'for reading (No such file or directory)`  **My fault, I haven't informed of those details.**

Answer (score -1):

try this `for d in words/*; do for f in ./words/$d/*{0..9}.txt; do awk -f script.awk $f; done`

Comment: There are several things wrong here: `for d in words/*` selects everything under `words` not only directories - you would need `for d in words/*/` to glob for dirs only then `for f in ./words/$d/*{0..9}.txt` is actually equivalent to `for f in ./words/words/*/*{0..9}.txt` so most likely not what OP wants and finally, you need the closing `done`. Also, don't forget to quote your vars.